# How to set, list, get breakpoints in classdef in octave?

Tags: debugging, octave

Suppose I have a classdef in a MyClass.m file with properties and methods like in the polynomial2 example found here https://octave.org/doc/v7.1.0/Creating-a-classdef-Class.html

I've confirmed that it's possible to set breakpoints in class methods using

```
dbstop in MyClass at MyClassMethod
```

as described here https://octave.org/doc/v7.1.0/Breakpoints.html

My questions are:

- Is it possible to use a line number instead of the method name?
- Is is possible to list the breakpoints in the class file?
- Is it possible to clear breakpoints only in that class file?

Since all of the above are possible for functions, I would suppose it should also be possible for classes.

Thank you